# Is there an antidote for caffeine, e.g. as a supplicant for caffeine-intolerant persons?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, pharmacology

First, let me state I'm **not** talking about a medical emergency. No one is in a serious condition.

My girlfriend is, we think, caffeine-intolerant. She loves the smell of coffee and the habit of coffee drinking, so naturally she risks drinking caffeinated beverages every now and then, even knowing she'll suffer. She experiences the regular effects of coffee, but they are uncomfortably strong and last much more time than usual. We've read that it's because her body metabolizes caffeine slowly, likely due to a gene mutation. We think it's not caffeine allergy.

We were wondering if there's kind of an antidote, a molecule which metabolizes or deactivates caffeine specifically. Then one example use could be

1. drink regular coffee;
2. wait some time (e.g. half an hour);
3. take a pill to take care of the excess caffeine in your bloodstream.

We're asking mostly out of curiosity - she's not that addicted to coffee as to actually take pills just to be able to drink it. The real (bio-chemical) question is - can an antidote, which targets a this very specific molecule, be actually manufactured? Or is it that it's not researched purely because of market size reasons?

Comment: Why not just drink de-caffinated coffee?

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant, she still gets some of the symptoms if she drinks decaf e.g. three days in a row. We think the prolonged exposure to even relatively small amounts of caffeine is what's bugging her.

Comment: `Is it that it's not researched?` Probably this. I've looked through literature and there seem not to be any references to any things studied which may sequester or adsorb caffeine, save for activated charcoal. People with hypersensitivity to caffeine usually have a gene variant which is involved in metabolizing caffeine in the liver. Aside from a hypothetical gene therapy, the best course of action would be to avoid it, especially if she is not in any way addicted. `Can an antidote be manufactured?` Yes, it is almost certainly possible, though I don't think it'd be profitable nor advisable.